# comparison of String with ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, activerecord, minitest, fixtures

My application gives users the opportunity to create events with a start and end time:

```
>> Event.where('end_time < ?', 1.days.ago).first
  Event Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "events".* FROM "events" WHERE (end_time < '2017-12-21 13:30:36.411209') ORDER BY "events"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Event id: 1, user_id: 1, place: "london", start_time: "2017-08-26 20:00", end_time: "2017-08-26 22:00", note: "Note", note_id: 355, picture: "dwarf_hammering.jpg", created_at: "2017-08-14 11:27:16", updated_at: "2017-08-14 11:27:16">
```

As you can see the `start_time` and `end_time` are `String` with a pre-defined format, and Active Record is able to compare them against a Time instance.

I created a Sidekiq job to delete all events that are older than one day:

```
class EventsCleanerWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform
    events = Event.where('end_time < ?', 1.days.ago)
    if events.any?
      events.delete_all
    end
  end
end
```

Inside `test/fixtures/events.yml` I created 6 events: two of them have an `end_time` older than one day, as the event below:

```
event3:
  user: John
  place: "London"
  start_time: 3.days.ago.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
  end_time: 2.days.ago.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
  note: "A thrilling adventure"
```

Then I created the following test:

```
def test_events_cleaner_worker_inline_mode
  assert Event.count == 6
  assert events(:event3).end_time < 1.days.ago
  EventsCleanerWorker.perform_async
  assert Event.all.reload.count == 4
  assert_equal 0, EventsCleanerWorker.jobs.size
end
```

However, when I run this test I receive the following error:

```
ArgumentError: comparison of String with ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone failed
```

This error is referred to `assert events(:event3).end_time < 1.days.ago` 
If I remove this line the test fails because the test expects `Event.all.reload.count` to be 6 instead of 4. 
 I have no idea why the string generated by `end_time` inside the events fixtures cannot be compared against Time, while this is possible in the dev environment.

Answer (score 0):

`start_time` and `end_time` in the fixture should be embed in `ERB` as follows:

```
event3:
  user: John
  place: "London"
  start_time: <%= 3.days.ago.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") %>
  end_time: <%= 2.days.ago.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") %>
  note: "A thrilling adventure"
```